# How to include hostname of the VM in syslog

Tags: vmware, syslog

I want to pass the hostname of the VM in each log message that is being sent by syslog client to syslog server. Is this possible?.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe the syslog messages have any ability to be modified prior to being sent.